# QMAIL Bounceback to original sender?

Tags: email

my QMAIL Server sends all bouncebacks and undelivered message notifications to anonymous@domain.com and not the original sender.  Is there any way to configure Qmail so that the sender receives the "undeliverable" bounce-back messages instead of this catch all account?

joe@abc.com sends mail to jill@xyz.com but jill@xyz.com doesn't exist.  xyz.com domain lets abc.com's qmail server know that it can't send that mail and anonymous@abc.com get's that notice.  How can joe@abc.com get the notice instead?